# Issue with smooth camera zoom in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, zooming

I am trying to make my camera smoothly zoom in and out whenever I use a mouse scroll wheel, but for some reason it zooms instantly and not smoothly.
This is how I update the zoom:

```
[SerializeField, Range(10, 100)] float scrollSpeed = 10f;
[SerializeField] Vector2 zoomAmount = Vector2.zero;

private float ScrollWheel
{
    get { return Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel"); }
}

private new Camera camera = null;

void Update()
{
    if (camera == null) return;

    UpdateZoom();
}

void UpdateZoom()
{
    pos = camera.transform.position;

    pos = Vector3.Lerp(pos, new Vector3(pos.x, pos.y - scrollSpeed * 10 * ScrollWheel, pos.z), Time.deltaTime * 2);
    pos.y = Mathf.Clamp(pos.y, zoomAmount.x, zoomAmount.y);

    camera.transform.position = pos;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're a little confused about `Lerp` (I was confused in the same way too when I started using it).  When you pass in a 0 for the time argument (the third argument), it will return your "starting" vector.  When you pass a value of 1 or more for the time argument, it will return your "ending" vector.  **However**, if you're passing `Time.deltaTime * 2`, then you'll be returning approximately the same interpolated vector every frame.  `Lerp` doesn't "track" how far it's already interpolated, so by passing in the same time value every frame, `Lerp` will never actually return your ending vector.  So rather than passing `Time.deltaTime * 2`, you'd need to do something like this

```
float interpolatedTime = 0;
void Update()
{
   var myVector = Vector3.Lerp(vector1, vector2, this.interpolatedTime);
   this.interpolatedTime += Time.deltaTime; 
}
```

How about something like this for your camera:

```
float zoomTime;
float zoomTarget;
float lastScrollWheelDirection;

void Update()
{
    // If this camera is currently zooming in and the player started zooming
    // out (or vice versa), reset the amount that is remaining to be zoomed
    if ((this.lastScrollWheelDirection > 0 && this.ScrollWheel < 0) ||
        (this.lastScrollWheelDirection < 0 && this.ScrollWheel > 0))
    {
        this.zoomTarget = 0;
    }
    if (this.ScrollWheel != 0)
    {
        this.lastScrollWheelDirection = this.ScrollWheel;
    }

    // zoomTarget is the total distance that is remaining to be zoomed.
    // Each frame that the scroll wheel is moved, we'll add a little more
    // to the distance that we want to zoom
    zoomTarget += this.ScrollWheel * this.scrollSpeed;

    // zoomTime is used to do linear interpolation to create a smooth zoom.
    // Each time the player moves the mouse wheel, we reset zoomTime so that 
    // we restart our linear interpolation
    if (this.ScrollWheel != 0)
    {
        this.zoomTime = 0;
    }

    if (this.zoomTarget != 0)
    {
        this.zoomTime += Time.deltaTime;

        // Calculate how much our camera will be moved this frame using linear
        // interpolation.  You can adjust how fast the camera zooms by
        // changing the divisor for zoomTime
        var translation = Vector3.Lerp(
            new Vector3(0, 0, 0),
            new Vector3(0, this.zoomTarget, 0),
            zoomTime / 4f);   // see comment above

        // Zoom the camera by the amount that we calculated for this frame
        this.transform.position -= translation;

        // Decrease the amount that's remaining to be zoomed by the amount 
        // that we zoomed this frame
        this.zoomTarget -= translation.y;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for such detail answer! :) It's much more clearer now with the whole lerping subject. I implemented your system and it works now, although sometimes if I scroll really fast it goes instantly into position at some points. It's much better now but still feels a bit rough on the edges if that makes sense.

Comment: Hmm... what do you mean it goes instantly into position?  If you scroll fast, this code will zoom faster, but it should always ease into the final position.  If you want it to zoom slower, you can increase that divisor on zoomTile (the `4f` in the example).  Otherwise could you give a bit more of an explanation about what it's doing incorrectly?  When I was testing it, I didn't experience any instantaneous jumping.

Comment: Also, when you're scrolling fast, are you maybe scrolling forward and the accidentally scroll backwards?  As soon as you start scrolling in the opposite direction, this code will stop zooming in the current direction; which will look like it jumped to position.  If you want to eliminate that behavior, comment out that top block in the code (the top two `if` statements).

Comment: Increased that divisor and now it's already much better! Thank very much for your help! :)